# Difference between using and not using a pointer inside a malloc

Tags: c

I just want to know the difference between malloc(sizeof(*some_structure)) and malloc(sizeof(some_structure)).

I am just learning about C and I have encountered some issues lately with this. I am sorry for the rookie question but I didn't know how to search for it on google.

Comment: This hardly depends on how some structure is defined.

Comment: What is the type of `some_structure` and is there maybe a `sizeof` missing? Please show some more code for context

Comment: Both examples are bad. PS put code in body of question. Its not FB, here are own rules

Comment: The first version will never work. A struct is no pointer and cannot be dereferenced. You probably mean `malloc(sizeof(*pointer_to_some_structure))` vs `malloc(sizeof(some_structure))`

Comment: This question is incomplete, to not say "sloppy", and with this very unclear. Voting to close for the reasons of the latter.

Comment: There is a lot of guessing going on in the answers below. (Mine is trying to answer the questin you asked, which is probably not helpful either. I did not notice how unclear it is, just found the naming of the variables weird...) Please try to rephrase your question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's say you have

```
typedef struct some_structure {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} some_structure;

int main(void)
{
    some_structure *hello = NULL;
}
```

- Then, `hello` is type of `some_structure *` : that's "pointer of structure".
- And `*hello` is type of `some_structure` : that's "some_structure".

The same kind happen for every level of pointer :

```
int main(void)
{
    some_structure **hello = NULL;
}
```

- Then, `hello` is type of `some_structure **` : that's "pointer of pointer of structure".
- And `*hello` is type of `some_structure *` : that's "pointer of some_structure".
- Finally, `**hello` is type of `some_structure` : that's "some_structure".

When you malloc something, you want to allocate the memory for the structure itself. Then you want to malloc the type of `some_structure` itself.

That's why you generally use `*some_structure`.

Why not using `sizeof(some_structure)` directly ?
Because in case of a change in your variable type.

With `some_structure *hello = malloc(sizeof(*hello))`, even if you change the type of `hello`, the malloc will be still valid.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the answer that I was looking for!.
(I am sorry for the bad examples and I had that issue at 4 am and wasn´t in a good mood haha.)

Answer (score 1):

The first is getting space, the size of which is indicated by a variable which is pointed to by a pointer named `some_structure`, which is a weird naming for a pointer.

The second is getting space, the size of which is indicated by a variable named `some_structure`, also weird naming for a variable which holds something similar to an integer.

Note, others have found the naming of the variables so weird that they (silently) assumed you were asking a completely different question. This answer here tries (maybe slightly stubbornly) to answer the question as asked.
Please consider clarifying your question. If the plausible guesses are correct you will find lots of answers already existing.
(And I will remove mine, if somebody pings me and gives me some hours time, because I have to leave now.)

Comment: @alk I still edited to help avoid the misunderstanding. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the definition of malloc, [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm), you can see that the malloc function expects a `size_t size` argument.

Therefore, the difference is the size you are requesting to allocate: A pointer to some_struct, or the size of the struct itself.

Note that in order to pass the requested size correctly, you have to use `sizeof()`:
`malloc(sizeof(*some_structure))` or `malloc(sizeof(some_structure))`

Comment: This seems to be the answer to a slightly different questions on `malloc(sizeof something)` instead of `malloc(somethign)`.

Comment: I will add the fact that he is missing a sizeof(), but otherwise this answering the question

Comment: Still guessing that OP means something different than written. Guessing well though...

Answer (score 0):

See the following code to know the difference:

```
struct abc
{
    int a, b, c;
    char d, e, f;
};

int main(){
    abc a;
    abc *b;
    printf("%zu %zu",sizeof(a), sizeof(b));
}
```

Output is:

```
16 8
```

Pointer has type of `long unsigned int`, that is why size is 8.

For `struct abc`, size = 4*3+1*3 = 15 (1 is added for padding)

While doing `some_struct` you are allocating the full memory of that structure, while in second case (`*some_struct`) you are allocating just the memory for pointer.

Comment: sorry, will edit it. but it won't make a difference

Comment: Well then it will be the answer to a slightly different questions on malloc(sizeof something) instead of malloc(somethign).

Comment: yeah, edited it, thanks:)

Comment: corrected it, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, as it lacks real code and even real definitions what you are really talking about. But I hope this might shed some light on the topic.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct a{
    int b;
    long long int c;
};

int main()
{
    struct a *foo; //this is just a pointer to not allocated memory
    foo = malloc(sizeof (*foo)); //allocation of the struct for the pointer

    foo->b = 2;
    foo->c = 3;

    struct a **bar; // pointer to the pointer of struct;
    bar = malloc(sizeof (foo)); //size of a pointer
    *bar = foo;

    printf("%d\n",(*bar)->b); //bar is a pointer to foo that points to your memory for the struct  
    printf("size of pointer %d\n",sizeof foo);
    printf("size of struct %d\n",sizeof *foo);
}
```